# SauceLabs selenium tests or interactive sessions fails with 'Browser failed to start' error message

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I try to run selenium tests on SauceLabs which works pretty well. But since a couple of days all my tests fails to start with the error message: 'Browser failed to start'. If I try to start an interactive sessions the same error messages appears. The browser/os combination seems to have no impact (I tried chrome, firefox, opera on mavericks, windows 7 and linux - all with the same result).

My setup looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractSeleniumTestBase implements SauceOnDemandSessionIdProvider {
    RemoteWebDriver driver;
    Selenium selenium; 


public DesiredCapabilities getCapabilities() {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(this.browser);
    capabilities.setCapability("version", this.version);
    capabilities.setCapability("platform", this.platform);
    return capabilities;
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    String serverUrl = System.getProperty("selenium.server");
    String baseUrl = System.getProperty("selenium.url");
    DesiredCapabilities c = getCapabilities();
    c.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    String name = getName() + " (on " + c.getBrowserName() + " "
            + c.getVersion() + " " + c.getPlatform() + ")\n";
    c.setCapability("name", name);
    System.out.print("\nTesting: " + name);

    this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(serverUrl), c);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    this.sessionId = driver.getSessionId().toString();
}
```

Comment: If you do not change your code, you should work with SourceLabs to solve this issue. Almost "connection" issue like this relates to your configurations

Comment: I tried three times to get in contact with the saucelabs customer support. That was actually pretty disappointing. All I got is a copy from the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the format in the sauce labs format:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 7");
caps.setCapability("version", "30");
```

What are the values that you use for this.version and this.platform.

Answer (score 0):

We have noticed this problem show up every once in a while. Manually starting a session within SauceLabs resulted in the same error. In short the problem is with SauceLabs. It usually gets fixed within 24 hours.

Unfortunately we have not received an official answer to the exact nature of the problem. Last time we saw this issue crop up on one of our accounts was on August 3rd around 11pm. Just had to wait for it to clear out the next day.